# CLOB field with XML data to DOM object in Java

Tags: java, oracle, dom, xml-parsing, clob

// employees.xml

```
<employees>
      <employee id="111">
        <firstName>Lokesh</firstName>
        <lastName>Gupta</lastName>
        <location>India</location>
    </employee>
    <employee id="222">
        <firstName>Alex</firstName>
        <lastName>Gussin</lastName>
        <location>Russia</location>
    </employee>
    <employee id="333">
        <firstName>David</firstName>
        <lastName>Feezor</lastName>
        <location>USA</location>
    </employee>
</employees>


public class Employee
{
   private Integer id;
   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;
   private String location;

   //Setters and Getters

   @Override
   public String toString()
   {
      return "Employee [id=" + id + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", location=" + location + "]";
   }
}
public static void main(String args[]) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException
   {
        List<Employee> employees = parseXML();
        System.out.println(employees);
   }

   private static List<Employee> parseXML() throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException
   {
      //Initialize a list of employees
      List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
      Employee employee = null;

      DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
      DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
      Document document = builder.parse(new File("employees.xml"));
      document.getDocumentElement().normalize();
      NodeList nList = document.getElementsByTagName("employee");
      for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++)
      {
         Node node = nList.item(temp);
         if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
         {
            Element eElement = (Element) node;
            //Create new Employee Object
            employee = new Employee();
            employee.setId(Integer.parseInt(eElement.getAttribute("id")));
            employee.setFirstName(eElement.getElementsByTagName("firstName").item(0).getTextContent());
            employee.setLastName(eElement.getElementsByTagName("lastName").item(0).getTextContent());
            employee.setLocation(eElement.getElementsByTagName("location").item(0).getTextContent());

            //Add Employee to list
            employees.add(employee);
         }
      }
      return employees;
   }







   output : [Employee [id=111, firstName=Lokesh, lastName=Gupta, location=India], 
Employee [id=222, firstName=Alex, lastName=Gussin, location=Russia], 
Employee [id=333, firstName=David, lastName=Feezor, location=USA]]






Question :
```

// Document document = builder.parse(new File("employees.xml"));

Now instead of employees.xml I have the xml data in table 'A's clob field "form_Data",I would  want to builder.parse(new File("employees.xml"))" replace this and get Document object

I have got the data from table A into result set : select form_Data from A;
In the result set I have got form_Data as a clob ,resultSet.getClob(1);  I am stuck here as to get the Document object for parsing from this clob

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Use your preferred search engine to find some tutorials. First find out how to read a CLOB field out of your database. Then how to parse a given XML in Java. Put these two together and you are finished. If you're running into problems, try to create a [minimal, reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You should also visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking your next question here.